# Asp.net URL Rewrite Rule with Regex

Tags: asp.net, regex, url-rewriting, web-config

I have rewrite rules on web.config file.

```
 <rewrite url="~/Login/(.+)$" to="~/Login.aspx?return=$1"/>
 <rewrite url="~/(.+)-xxx-(.+)$" to="~/Post.aspx?ost_name=$1&amp;post_id=$2"/>
```

First one for redirect url after login.
Second one for posts.

If users try login or click comment on post page they will go to login page with redirect url.

```
 protected void lnkLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["GoBackUrl"] = Request.RawUrl.ToString().Replace("/", "$");
         base.Response.Redirect("~/Login/" + Session["GoBackUrl"].ToString());
    }
```

For example

```
domain.com/Login/$post_name-xxx-post_id
```

After login they will turn back to post page.

But with this rules they are not going login page.
Url is changing as

```
 domain.com/Login/$post_name-xxx-post_id
```

but user stays same page.
How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this example from [Devrim Altinkurt's](https://www.daltinkurt.com/URL-Rewriter-ile-akilli-urller-olusturma-Tam-cozum)(lang:Tr) page and wrote him. He helped me.

**Solution:**
"processing="stop"

```
<rewrite url="~/Login/(.+)$" to="~/Login.aspx?return=$1" "processing="stop/>
 <rewrite url="~/(.+)-xxx-(.+)$" to="~/Post.aspx?post_name=$1&amp;post_id=$2"/>
```

When you don't write. Application looks all rules and firing last match
If you got same Url's you should use this. One more detail : rule ranks are important.